# How to save particular elements from loop if condition has been made

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

I'm working on chat in banking application. The function I'm struggling with is suppose to check if admin is online basing on text line in txt file. If admin is online the line says"ONLINE" and if offline says "OFFLINE". My loop checks all of the admin accounts and I want it to separate the ones where condition has been made so I can display the particular ones.

```
def who_is_online(self):
        content = []
        for files in os.listdir("D:/banki_projects/admin/"):
            with open("D:/banki_projects/admin/"+files, "r") as file:
                lines = file.readlines()
                if lines[3] in files == "ONLINE":
                    content.append(file)
                    self.info = tk.Label(self, text='admin is online '+content, fg="green")
                    self.info.pack()
                    self.start = tk.Button(self, text="start chat")
                    self.start.pack()
                else:
                    self.info = tk.Label(self, text='admin is offlinee', fg="red")
                    self.info.pack()
```

Comment: this makes no sense `if lines[3] in files == "ONLINE":`. This makes sense `if lines[3] == "ONLINE":`

Comment: Yes I have changed that after qucik consideration. Anyway how can I separate the files where this condition has been made ?